# Openshift snapshot restore / file permission

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I started with the Aerogear quickstart cartridge. Now I want to take a snapshot to edit the `bin/control` file, as I have no permission on this if I `ssh` into the cartridge.

The problem is that the file in `aerogear-push/bin/control` is not restored and stays the same old file after I do a `rhc snapshot restore`.

I have to change the control file as the file needs to be changed for the upcoming openshift update on 15th September..

Any hints? 
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The reason the restore isn't overwriting those files with the new fixes is because the restore isn't being done as root and therefore those bin files won't be overwritten. If you're wanting to update your application because of the changes being made, I would suggest running the `rhc app create <newappname> --from-app <current app name>` to essentially clone your application but re-deploy with the latest cartridge updates.